# Problems to change colors in vistime

Tags: r, vistime

I recently did the update for the vistime package but since, I cannot change the colors anymore. If I run this code:

```
pres <- data.frame(Position = rep(c("President", "Vice"), each = 3),
               Name = c("Washington", rep(c("Adams", "Jefferson"), 2), "Burr"),
               start = c("1789-03-29", "1797-02-03", "1801-02-03"),
               end = c("1797-02-03", "1801-02-03", "1809-02-03"),
               color = c('#cbb69d', '#603913', '#c69c6e'),
               fontcolor = c("black", "white", "black"))
```

`vistime::vistime(pres, events="Position", groups="Name", title="Presidents of the USA")`

I have like the "default" colors (6 colors in total instead of the 3 mentioned in the code) that appear on the timeline.

Does somebody else have the same problem?

Comment: Should it be `fontcolors` and `colors` (plural)?

Comment: I tried but it doesn't change anything...

Comment: What is the version of `vistime` you are using?

Comment: It is the version 0.8.0.

Comment: Considering the upvotes this question is getting I am guessing you are not the only one with this problem. I would suggest raising and issue on GitHub here https://github.com/shosaco/vistime/issues

Answer (score 0):

I am the maintainer of the package `vistime`. Unfortunately, this was a bug in the 0.8.0 version and was fixed in 0.8.1. Consider upgrading - version 1.0.0 will be out very soon!